# Moving an array held by a unique_ptr into a vector's array storage

Tags: c++, vector, move, unique-ptr

Is there a way to move a unique_ptr

```
unique_ptr<int[]> foo;
```

into a vector?

```
vector<int> bar;
```

Comment: What would be the point of it?

Comment: Note that this would require not only changing the storage but also the size and capacity to be that of the array.

Comment: @juanchopanza the point would be to avoid the cost of a copy.

Comment: @huitlarc but why do you need the `unique_ptr` in the first place? You could store the data in another vector and then swap or move it into `bar`.

Comment: Would there be any other costs in making this change? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18471844/2721254

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot just hand `vector` a piece of memory and expect it to use that as its array storage. A `vector`'s storage must come from the allocator that the `vector` uses.

You could try to use allocator gimmicks to pawn the memory off to the `vector` in some way. But even that would be tricky, as the `vector` can allocate as many `int`s as it wants, regardless of what size you tell it.

You can move the contents of a `unique_ptr` into an *element* of the array. Say, if you had a `vector<unique_ptr<int[]>>`. But you can't just slap a piece of memory into a `vector`.