# unique_ptr<int[]> or vector<int>?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

If you don't need dynamic growth and don't know the size of the buffer at compile time, when should `unique_ptr<int[]>` be used instead of `vector<int>` if at all?

Is there a significant performance loss in using `vector` instead of `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Why not use a std::array?

Comment: @Bart He doesn't need to grow the storage once allocated, that doesn't mean he knows the size at compile time.

Comment: @Bart I've updated the question to assume the size of the buffer is not known at compile time.

Comment: Even if the size was known at compile time, there might be reasons to dynamically allocate it, like if it is too large, or if it needs to outlive the scope in which it is created. Then the `std::array` becomes a third option: `std::unique_ptr<std::array<int,LARGE_N>>`, which is not nicer than any of the alternatives...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no performance loss in using `std::vector` vs. `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. The alternatives are not exactly equivalent though, since the vector could be grown and the pointer cannot (this can be and advantage or a disadvantage, did the vector grow by mistake?)

There are other differences, like the fact that the values will be initialized in the `std::vector`, but they won't be if you `new` the array (unless you use *value-initialization*...).

At the end of the day, I personally would opt for `std::vector<>`, but I still code in C++03 without `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Also, let's not forget that there's no size information with the `unique_ptr` method.

Answer (score 13):

If you're in a position where `vector<int>` is even a possibility, you probably want to go with that except in extreme and rare circumstances.  And even then, a custom type instead of `unique_ptr<int[]>` may well be the best answer.

So what the heck is `unique_ptr<int[]>` good for? :-)

`unique_ptr<T[]>` really shines in two circumstances:

`1.`  You need to handle a malloc/free resource from some legacy function and you would like to do it in a modern exception safe style:

```
void
foo()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[], void(*)(void*)> p(strdup("some text"), std::free);
    for (unsigned i = 0; p[i]; ++i)
        std::cout << p[i];
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

`2.`  You've need to temporarily secure a new[] resource before transferring it onto another owner:

```
class X
{
    int* data_;
    std::string name_;

    static void validate(const std::string& nm);
public:
    ~X() {delete [] data_;}

    X(int* data, const std::string& name_of_data)
        : data_(nullptr),
          name_()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> hold(data);  // noexcept
        name_ = name_of_data;               // might throw
        validate(name_);                    // might throw
        data_ = hold.release();             // noexcept
    }
};
```

In the above scenario, `X` owns the pointer passed to it, whether or not the constructor succeeds.  This particular example assumes a `noexcept` default constructor for `std::string` which is not mandated.  However:

1. This point is generalizable to circumstances not involving `std::string`.
2. A `std::string` default constructor that throws is lame.

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector` stores the length of both the size of the variable and the size of the allocated data along with the pointer to the data it's self. `std::unique_ptr` just stores the pointer so there may be a small gain in using `std::unique_ptr`.

No one has yet mentioned the vector provides iterators and function such and `size()` where as unique ptr does not. So if iterators are needed use `std::vector`

Answer (score 4):

C++14 introduces std::dynarray for that purpose.

Now, between these two constructions :

1. `auto buffer = std::make_unique<int[]>( someCount );`
2. `auto buffer = std::vector<int>( someCount, someValue );`

The first gives you an uninitialized array of int but the second initializes it with a value ( 0 if not provide ). So if you do not need the memory to be initialized because you will overwrite it somehow later with something more complex than `std::fill`, choose 1, if not, choose 2.

Comment: I thought `dynarray` was introduced to troll C++ programmers.

Comment: @Mystical The story behind `dynarray`is more subtil than a basic troll. It requires not so much skill to write a basic `dynarray` as a fixed size `vector` with standard dynamic allocation. But the real secret of that object lies in letting the compiler decide where allocating the memory, it may be on the heap, but it may be on the stack. And this is something impossible to do simply even with C++11.

Comment: It is unclear whether `dynarray` is the solution to the problem. It depends on whether the data can be safely allocated in the stack or not (`dynarray` does not mandate allocations to be in the stack, but the intention is that they will be). If the data needs to outlive the scope, for example, `dynarray` won't be the first choice.

Comment: `After reviewing national body comments to n3690, this library component was voted out from C++14 working paper into a separate Technical Specification. This container is not a part of the draft C++14 as of n3797` ([source](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/container/dynarray.html), `std::dynarray` page [has been removed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray) from cppreference on April 2017).

Answer (score 1):

Objective Part:

No, there probably shouldn't be a significant performance difference between the two (though I suppose it depends on the implementation and you should measure if it's critical).

Subjective Part:

`std::vector` is going to give you a well known interface with `.size()` and `.at()` and iterators, which will play nicely with all sorts of other code.  Using `std::unique_ptr` gives you a more primitive interface and makes you keep track of details (like the size) separately.  Therefore, barring other constraints, I would prefer `std::vector`.